# how to check key existence for dictionary within a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

In below code, how can I check key existence for dictionary within a dictionary?

Current execution throws key existence error.

**Output,
For Key "a", another key "X" with both values 1 and 2**

Do we have any better collection for this?

```
 var data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();

        foreach (var j in GetTopData())
        {
            foreach (var p in BottomData())
            {
                if (data.Keys.Contains(j.ToString()))
                {
                    data[j].Add(p.Name, p.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    data.Add(j, new Dictionary<string, object> { { p.Name, p.Value } });
                }
            }
        }
```

Here are the data classes,

```
private static List<TempData> BottomData()
    {
        return new List<TempData>
        {
            new TempData{ Name="X", Value=1},
            new TempData{ Name="X", Value=2}
        };
    }

    private static List<string> GetTopData()
    {
        return new List<string> { "a"};
    }

public class TempData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary` class has a `ContainsKey` method, which would simplify part of your code.

Comment: Take a step back and explain what the problem is you are trying to solve. Perhaps also explain the output you are hoping to see for your sample inputs above.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you are looking for something that takes two strings as a key and can contain multiple values for each combination of these keys?

Comment: yes, correct, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need one key to contain multiple values, `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>` will not work for you (it allows only 1 value for particular key). You can use `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<object>>>`, but it is hard to read and difficult to work with. So I thing it is better to use Dictionary, where both keys are combined into one as shown bellow in CombinedKey class (in C# 7.0, `ValueTuple<string, string>` will work too):

```
public class CombinedKey
{
    public string Key1;
    public string Key2;

    // It is necessary to override Equals and GetHashCode to make
    // it work properly as a dictionary key.
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var otherCombinedKey = obj as CombinedKey;

        return otherCombinedKey != null
            && otherCombinedKey.Key1 == this.Key1
            && otherCombinedKey.Key2 == this.Key2;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Key1.GetHashCode() ^ Key2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
Dictionary<CombinedKey, List<object>> data = new Dictionary<CombinedKey, List<object>>();

foreach (var j in GetTopData())
{
    foreach (var p in BottomData())
    {
        var key = new CombinedKey() { Key1 = j, Key2 = p.Name };
        List<object> list;
        if(!data.TryGetValue(key, out list))
        {
            data[key] = list = new List<object>();
        }
        list.Add(p.Value);
    }
}
```

If your data are immutable, you could also use [`Lookup<CombinedKey, object>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be simplified to:

```
        var data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<object>>>();

        foreach (var j in GetTopData())
        {
            foreach (var p in BottomData())
            {
                Dictionary<string, List<object>> values;
                var existed = data.TryGetValue(j, out values);

                if (!existed)
                    values = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

                List<Object> list;

                var existed2 = values.TryGetValue(p.Name, out list);
                if (!existed2)
                    list = new List<object>();

                list.Add(p.Value);

                if (!existed)
                    data.Add(j, values);

                if (!existed2)
                    values.Add(p.Name, list);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check for existing data in both of the dictionaries. Currently you are checking existence in just one dictionary:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();

            foreach (var j in GetTopData())
            {
                foreach (var p in BottomData())
                {
                    if(data.ContainsKey(j.ToString()))
                    {
                        var mydict = data[j.ToString()];
                        if (!mydict.ContainsKey(p.Name))
                            data[j].Add(p.Name, p.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data.Add(j, new Dictionary<string, object> { { p.Name, p.Value } });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I suspect by `if (!mydict.ContainsKey(p.ToString()))` you meant `if (!mydict.ContainsKey(p.Name))`

Comment: but we need to add both 1 and 2 for X, currently only 1 is added

Comment: That is why you need to explain what you want @user584018 - that simply isn't possible with the data structures you have chosen. You need to explain what output you are hoping for.

Comment: Output, For Key "a", another key "X" with both values 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question **how to check key existence for dictionary within a dictionary in C#**:

You can check this by using Linq like this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HNpPYs) :

```
bool keyExistance = data.Any(x=>x.Value.ContainsKey(keyTocheck));
```

But before that you have to fix the errors in your code.

Comment: ContainsKey is generally a bad idea when doing Dictionary access, if you plan to lookup the value straight afterwards. TryGetValue has the benefit of doing only a single lookup, rather than two.